# Codeiginter Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object after uploading website

Tags: codeigniter

i'm using code php Codeiginter  to build website with apis in localhost everything working correctly after upload website this message showing for me after

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

this api method :

```
public function getAdditionalsByAreaId($areaId)
{
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") :

        $this->apiToken = $_SERVER['HTTP_APITOKEN'];

        $partnerId = $this->jwtc->getUserIdFromToken($this->apiToken);

        if (!count($this->PartnersModel->getPartnerInfoByToken($partnerId))) :
            $this->output
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode($this->resultheaders->forbidden(), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
            return;
        endif;


        if (!$this->checkIfAreaForPartner($partnerId, $areaId)) :
            $this->output
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode($this->resultheaders->forbidden(), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
            return;
        endif;

        $this->header = $this->resultheaders->success();

        $rs = $this->AreasModel->getAdditionalsByAreaId($areaId);

        $result = array(
            'header' => $this->header,
            'list' => $rs
        );
        $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_output(json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

    endif;
}

private function getAdditionalsByAreaId($areaId)
{
    return $this->AreasModel->getAdditionalsByAreaId($areaId);
}
```

and this function to get api result :

```
    public function getAdditionalsByAreaId($areaId)
    {
//
        $curl = curl_init($this->datalayer->getApiUrl() . 'partners/areas/getAdditionalsByAreaId/' . $areaId);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'ApiToken:' . $this->datalayer->getApiToken(),
            )
        );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // Make it so the data coming back is put into a string
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return json_decode($result);
    }
```

where is my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem , the problem was in , data revived `names` was having space like :

```
$_POST['first_name '];
```

Solution just i removed space to be :

```
 $_POST['first_name '];
```